# What does simple operation do in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

What does the simple operation, A^(1/2), where A is a positive definite matrix, do in Matlab? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> Matrix power. X^p is X to the power p, if p is a scalar. If p is an integer, the power is computed by repeated squaring. If the integer is negative, X is inverted first. For other values of p, the calculation involves eigenvalues and eigenvectors, such that if [V,D] = eig(X), then X^p = V*D.^p/V.

As per [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html).